# What does an express app instance give you over an express router instance?

Tags: node.js, express

I've come across an interesting situation where we're using express app composition:

```
const rootApp = express();
const moduleOne = express();
const moduleTwo = express();

rootApp.use(moduleOne);
rootApp.use(moduleTwo);

rootApp.listen(3000);
```

Each of these `module` apps have their own routers, middleware, etc. and I was wondering what are some advantages and disadvantages of having app composition versus router composition at a higher level.

Answer (score 3):

It generally allows for better isolation and use of middleware. For example I tend to roll with multiple Express Applications (composed together) when building CRUD based apps which use Single Page Web Apps (React, Ember, Angular, etc). This allows me to attach different headers to each incredibly easier.

It also makes it very easy to move each application into it's own repo, this could be useful if you later on wish to run each application as it's own service. You could then use something like nginx to route to two apps. For example:

```
myapp.com/api/auth -> authentication express app
myapp.com/api -> general API
myapp.com/ -> light weight express app which serves the front end.
```

This makes it much easier to scale your application later on, and allows more fine grained control.

In the short term, the control over various middleware is the thing I find most useful about composing express apps vs composing express routers. It means you can do "app.use()" and tends to read a lot better to other developers coming to your project.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely agree on the who app composition, app separation, nice migration path to microservices, etc. but was curious whether the actually app instance has any other useful functionality over the traditional router instance

Answer (score 0):

An `app` is a `router` object with a few more properties and methods related to the overall state of your app.  Properties on the `app` object like `app.locals` or methods like `app.listen()` apply to your whole app, not just to a set of routes.  Other than that though, you can think of an `app` like a subclass of a `router` with all the capabilities of a router with added app properties.

If you look in the [source code for the `app` object](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L137), you will see that it has a router in its instance data (not sure why they didn't actually subclass it):

```
this._router = new Router({...});
```

And, then further examination of the code shows that `app.use()`, `app.get()`, etc... all flow through that above router.

So, your `app` objects works just perfectly fine if all you need is one router.  But, there are reasons to use more than one router.  For example, if you have a series of sub-routes (say everything that starts with `/api/xxx`) that you want to do some authentication on, but lots of other routes don't require that auth, then you can create a router for `/api`, define middleware on only that router that checks your auth and then define the sub-routes on that router and you get a nice encapsulated definition of sub-routes all with their own middleware.

Comment: @Detuned - Does this answer your question?